# Drawing white and black balls from a container with specified numbers of each

Tags: probability

I cannot understand how to solve this problem:

> From a vessel containing 3 white and 5 black balls, 4 balls are transferred into an empty vessel. From this vessel a ball is drawn and is found to be white. What is the probability that out of four balls transferred 3 are white and 1 black?

Answer (score 2):

I would find all the possible first draws (4B 0W), (3B 1W), (2B 2W), (1B 3W) and give each of them a probability of happening.  Then, from each of those nodes, find the probability that a white is drawn from them.  Multiply the two probabilities together in each case.  Then make a fraction $$\frac{\text{probability of drawing a white from 1B 3W}}{\text{sum of all probabilities that led to drawing a white ball}}$$